# Remove remote git tag from NetBeans IDE

Tags: git, netbeans

I am using Netbeans 11.1, and Git.

This is what happened:

1. i created a tag in my local repository (it is called v.8.1.0);
2. i have pushed my tag onto the remote repository. After this operation i can see that the remote tag has been created;
3. For some reason i decided to delete my tag (v.8.1.0) and i did that by using
   Git->Branch/Tag->Manage tags->Select the desired tag->delete;
   This deleted the tag locally, but i could still see the tag on the remote. So i tried to push my whole project onto the remote, but it did not work: even after that i can still see the tag in the remote repository.

NOTE: if i open the repository browser functionality(Git->Repository->Repository Browser) i can see that while Netbeans keeps track of remote branches, it does not keep track of remote tags. In fact i can only see local tags:

[image]

So, what should i do in order to delete the remote tag from my IDE *without opening remote repository and without opening a git command line and launch the commands manually*?

Comment: can't you remove the tag directly from the remote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to delete a tag from the remote repo using NetBeans 11.1 or 11.2. NetBeans supports only the deletion of branches.

I created the [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/NETBEANS/issues/NETBEANS-3929?filter=allissues) and added the [PR](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/pull/1995).

UPDATED: fixed in 12.0

Comment: @BabaNew, just let you know it was fixed in 12.0